# Which data structure is best to delete an element from a given position array or linklist

Tags: data-structures

A list of 1000 numbers is there which 500th element is to be deleted , which data structure to use array or linked list and why?

Comment: I suggest you write a benchmark, and then tell us. IMHO both data structures should have the same complexity for deletion.

Comment: If you're open to using a *custom data-structure*, you might want to use a `Doubly-Linked-List` along with a `HashMap`. Read [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-first-non-repeating-character-stream-characters/) for usage.

Comment: You should be able to argue which will be faster based on a fundamental understanding of how each works. Where did you get stuck? Do you understand how deletion works in each case? Do you know what an array and a linked-list look like?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the order of items when you delete? That is, if you have the array `[1,4,7,5,6]` and you delete the third item (the value 7), is the expected result `[1,4,5,6]`, or would `[1,4,6,5]` be acceptable?

Comment: No, u cannot change the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete the 500th element, this will happen:

```
ArrayList: will copy each item starting from 501 until 1000 to its backing array, replacing item 500 (I'll call this "499 change operations")
LinkedList: will find the 500th element by looping through the items of the list 500 times. Then remove the item by unlinking it, e.g. from 499 -> 500 -> 501 to 499 -> 501 (I'll call it "500 access operations and 2 change operations")
```

Since change operations such as add/delete take longer than access operations, the time it took to delete the middle item of a 100 million Integers LinkedList was 307ms, while the same operation on an ArrayList took 784ms.

To answer your question, if **time to delete** is the most important perspective, the LinkedList should be chosen.

As a side note: creating the ArrayList with 100 million integers took 2.7 seconds, while creating the LinkedList took 12.4 seconds (and much more memory).

Answer (score 0):

**Deletion in Linked list:**

Deleting the first node is easiest , as you have a pointer to first node.
So , make pointer point to second node which takes **O(1)** time.

Deleting any other node however will be carried out in two steps:

**Step1**. Reaching the node to be deleted. For this we have to scan each node one by one till we reach the node (no random access). This will take **O(n)** time.

**Step2**. After finding it we need to detatch it from the list. This will take **O(1)** time.

So **Totat time = O(1) + O(n)**.

**Deletion in array:**

Deletion of any node in array is same always. There is no special case.

**Step1**. First you access the array element , which takes **O(1)** time.

**Step2**. Then you delete it by moving all other elements after that one position backwards.This takes **O(n)** time.

**Totat time = O(1) + O(n)**.

So deleting the first element in array will be more costly than deleting the first element in linked list.

In all other cases , **asymptotially** , deletion should be equally costly in both arrays and linked lists.
But if we actually count the time , I think deletion/insertion is faster in linked list compared to arrays.

Comment: *I think deletion/insertion is faster in linked list compared to arrays.* I think you might be surprised. If you want to delete the last item in a linked list of length 100, you have to traverse 100 links. If you want to delete the first item in an array of 100 items, you have to move the 99 following items up one space. A block move of n items is likely to be a whole lot faster than n pointer assignments and de-references.

Comment: To delete the last node in a linked list , we will not need to make *n pointer assignments and de-references*. Just one pointer reassignment for the second-last node , make it point to NULL. Though it is true that we will need to traverse through n links i.e O(n) time. This might take time depending upon how far are these nodes in memory but generally they are not that far apart to cause a major time problem.

Comment: My point is that traversing the n links will quite likely take longer than a block move of n array elements. Think of what's involved in traversing the n links, as opposed to a block move. Traversing a link is, bassically, `node = node->next;`, which is a dereference and an assignment, and probably will incur a cache miss. In contrast, the runtime library supplied block move will take advantage of the CPU's block move instructions, which are *very* fast, and incur a lot fewer cache misses. In short, *traversing* 100 pointers will take longer than *moving* 100 pointers.